# Tamanho de célula automatica em Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Olá, tenho um projeto que tem uma *tableview* com células customizadas, até o Swift 1.1 o método `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` no `viewDidLoad` e o número de linhas em 0, já eram suficientes para as minhas células se adaptarem ao conteúdo de caracteres contido nelas. Porém depois do Swift 1.2 elas não se adaptam mais, alguém poderia me dar uma luz sobre isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca também o tamanho estimado (Valor que seja realistico pra seu caso, um caso geral apenas para "acelerar" a computação):

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // Talvez isso funcione no momento não tenho como testar.
```

Caso ainda persista o problema implemente estes métodos do UITableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Obg Otávio, deu certo inserindo somenta a linha... func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}